# UIView and UIImage preloading

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiview, uiimage, preload

I've got magazine app and I want to know If is there any way how to preload UIView and UIImages?

My views structure:

```
MagazineView
  -> pageView
    -> imageContainerView
       -> image 
    -> imageContainerView
       -> image
    -> textView
  -> pageView
etc...
```

So my question is - How to preload images before views are visible? I want to make some Cache with 3 or 5 pages and makes threads for loading views. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that to 'preload images' means downloading them before they are actually used so there is no delay when displaying them.

What you could do is download the images first using `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]`, then either dump the data into a file using `writeToFile:atomically:` on your NSData instance, or simply keep the data in heap in the NSData for future reuse.

Then when you need it, you can create UIImage using either `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile]` or `[UIImage imageWithData:]`.

Note that if you save the cache to files, save those files in the cache folder, not in the documents folder, or mark them with the attribute that makes them skipped when syncing to iCloud, otherwise your app will be rejected by Apple.

Also keep in mind that downloading those images can taken long, timeout, or fail. You should do all this in a background thread in a way that does not block the main thread, have a visual indicator that the application is not frozen and have a fallback for the case where the downloads fail or the cache is flushed (if you save the images to files)

Comment: No I've got all images downloaded... When I mean preload I mean draw images but on background. Thx for reply...

Answer (score 0):

After you load images as J_D described, just put them into pageView and set them Hidden to YES. Every time you want to switch page, just call some method, that will pre-load new images and show those, which are already downloaded (set Hidden to NO) ;-). 
Hope this will help you to solve your problem...